# Multiple attachments/GmailApp.sendEmail/Apps Script/Not working

Tags: google-apps-script

Question = I have 5 variables. They have these files name. I want to attach them. It gives iterator error or some error in the line of Gmailapp.send (regarding attachments). The code was working fine but stopped working when I added the attachments part to the code. My drive has no other files with these names.

Can someone please correct my code. Please mention the code as I do not understand coding much. I need solution by file names only (not fileId if it is possible).

**I will be immensely thankful for this**

My Code:

````
function BulkEmail() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Assets");
  
 var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0]
  .signature; // variable signature is set

  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); //gives user name
  var firstpart = user.split('.')[0]; //gives first part of user name
  var displaycustomer = uppercase + " from IM";

var docinv = DriveApp.getFilesByName('1_Investor Presentation_K.pdf');
var docbu = DriveApp.getFilesByName('2_Business Update_As on April-2023.pdf');
var docfs = DriveApp.getFilesByName('3_Audited Financial Statements_FY23.pdf')
var doccr = DriveApp.getFilesByName('4_Crisil_Rationale_31.May.23.pdf')
var docxi = DriveApp.getFilesByName('6_Calculation_XIRR - Pricing Model v4.xlsx')

 //var last Row
 var Avals = sheet.getRange("h43:h47").getValues();
 var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length; 
 var lastRow = Alast+43;
 Logger.log('Last Row: ' + lastRow);

for (var i=43; i<lastRow; i++) 
{

var stage = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    Logger.log('Stage is: ' + stage);

  var address = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    Logger.log('Email Address is: ' + address);

    var subject = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    Logger.log('Subject is: ' + subject);

//K-1st Email
if(stage == "K-1st Email")
{
var body = "<HTML><BODY>"

+"Hello," 
    +"<BR><BR>"+
    "I hope this email finds you."

    +"<BR><BR>"
   

+"</BODY></HTML>";

GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {htmlBody : body + signature,name:displaycustomer,
attachments:[docinv.next(),docbu.next(),docxi.next(),doccr.next(),docfs.next()]});  
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

In your script, I guessed that each file of `DriveApp.getFilesByName('1_Investor Presentation_K.pdf')` and so on might be only one file. If my understanding is correct, when I saw your script, I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to that `next()` is used in the loop.

By the way, it seems that `account.isDefault` returns the boolean type.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function BulkEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Assets");
  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(account => account.isDefault)[0].signature;
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
  var firstpart = user.split('.')[0]; // It seems that this is not used.
  var displaycustomer = uppercase + " from IM";
  var files = [
    '1_Investor Presentation_K.pdf',
    '2_Business Update_As on April-2023.pdf',
    '3_Audited Financial Statements_FY23.pdf',
    '4_Crisil_Rationale_31.May.23.pdf',
    '6_Calculation_XIRR - Pricing Model v4.xlsx'
  ];
  var attachments = files.reduce((ar, f) => {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(f);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      ar.push(file.next().getBlob());
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("h43:h47").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = Alast + 43;
  Logger.log('Last Row: ' + lastRow);
  for (var i = 43; i < lastRow; i++) {
    var stage = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    Logger.log('Stage is: ' + stage);
    var address = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    Logger.log('Email Address is: ' + address);
    var subject = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    Logger.log('Subject is: ' + subject);
    if (stage == "K-1st Email") {
      var body = "<HTML><BODY>" + "Hello," + "<BR><BR>" + "I hope this email finds you." + "<BR><BR>" + "</BODY></HTML>";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body + signature,
        name: displaycustomer,
        attachments
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Or, as another modification, when your for loop is also modified, how about the following modification?

```js
function BulkEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Assets");
  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(account => account.isDefault)[0].signature;
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
  var firstpart = user.split('.')[0]; // It seems that this is not used.
  var displaycustomer = uppercase + " from IM";
  var files = [
    '1_Investor Presentation_K.pdf',
    '2_Business Update_As on April-2023.pdf',
    '3_Audited Financial Statements_FY23.pdf',
    '4_Crisil_Rationale_31.May.23.pdf',
    '6_Calculation_XIRR - Pricing Model v4.xlsx'
  ];
  var attachments = files.reduce((ar, f) => {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(f);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      ar.push(file.next().getBlob());
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("h43:h47").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = Alast + 43;
  Logger.log('Last Row: ' + lastRow);
  var values = sheet.getRange("H43:J" + (lastRow - 1).getValues(); // or sheet.getRange("H43:J" + lastRow).getValues();
  values.forEach(([address, stage, subject]) => {
    Logger.log('Stage is: ' + stage);
    Logger.log('Email Address is: ' + address);
    Logger.log('Subject is: ' + subject);
    if (stage == "K-1st Email") {
      var body = "<HTML><BODY>" + "Hello," + "<BR><BR>" + "I hope this email finds you." + "<BR><BR>" + "</BODY></HTML>";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body + signature,
        name: displaycustomer,
        attachments
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when the filename is not correct, the file is not attached. Please be careful about this.
- In this modification, it supposes that each file of each filename is only one file. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [next() of Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next())
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)